# Dynamically pass columns into when otherwise functions in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am using withColumn with when otherwise to update a column value

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("col_1", when(col("col_1") > col("col_2"),col("col_2")).otherwise(col("col_1")))
```

but my requirement is to make this statement generic so some one can pass a string like
`"col(\"col_1\") > col(\"col_2\")"` and it can be passed to when function
this string can have logical operators like `&&`, `||`

Is their a way to pass string expression into Column?
Or is their another way to pass these values dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is helpful -
**`you can pass filter variable directly as below`**

```
val filter = "col_1>col_2"
val df2 = df.withColumn("col_1", expr(s"case when ($filter) then col_2 else col_1 end")
```